# I hope to obtain the peak value and peak length of the pulse signal of each channel when pulse signals appear in multiple channels at the same time

Tags: matlab, math, signal-processing

I collected data from three channels of FPGA with a sampling frequency of 150MHZ,one minute duration. Now I need to find out when pulse signals appear in the three channels at the same time, the peak value of the pulse in each channel, and the length of the pulse. What algorithm can be used in this scenario? ? and how it should be implemented

I want to use the wavelet transform algorithm or the fast Fourier algorithm, but I don’t know if it can be used here because the real-time requirements are very high.

Comment: Wavelets and FFTs are useless for the task you describe here.  You're interested in time-domain information, not frequency-domain.  Are these digital signals?  You can add them together to find when all three are asserted.

Comment: simple linear search + sliding window ... will do if you know more about the signal you could optimize window size and search step to accelerate detection itself depends on signal show input sample data containing both signal   and no signal (probably noise)

Comment: Is there any algorithm available to obtain peak data? My data is as follows. I have found many filtering algorithms, but the results are not good，0.017700195
0.017089844
0.017089844
0.017089844
0.017089844
0.017089844
0.01739502
0
0
0
0.01953125
0.020751953
0.017700195
0.01739502
0.01739502
0.017089844
0.018310547